# Simple Netty Server not sending response

Tags: netty

I'm writing custom protocol search service running on TCP. Everything works perfect when using EmbeddedChannel for testing. To test futher, I wrote a Server and add the handlers up. With a request from a plain java Socket client, server received the data, process and send back a response. However, the response does not reach the client socket. I thought may be I have messed up with the large channelPipeline. So I reduce the implementation to one Inbound Handler only. Still doesn't work. Can someone help here?.

Server:

```
public void start() throws Exception{
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        final KaiExceptionHandler kaiExceptionHandler = new KaiExceptionHandler();
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
                        pipeline.addLast(new SimpleHandler());
                    }
                });
        ChannelFuture future = b.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9400)).sync();
        future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception {
                if(channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
                    LOGGER.info("Kai Server is bounded to '{}'", "localhost:9400");
                }else {
                    LOGGER.error("Failed to bound Kai to 'localhost:9400'", channelFuture.cause());
                }
            }
        });
        future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
```

Simple Handler:

```
public class SimpleHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Client is not seeing this", charset));
    ctx.flush();
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.flush();
} }
```

Test Client. A not-neat implementation. However, just for test.

```
public class TestClient {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9400);
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
    int r = 0;
    socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    System.out.println("Reading...");
    while ((r = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        sb.append(new String(buffer).trim());
    }
    System.out.println("String: " + sb.toString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your test program is assuming that the connection gets closed after writing the data, and its assuming strings aren't fragmented in the case of sending multibyte characters.

If the wait till socket closure is intentional, you need to change your `write` statement to the following:

```java
ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Client is not seeing this", charset))
    .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

This way of communication is inefficient however, because you need to re-open another socket connection everytime you want to say something to the server. The best way would be making the protocol either line based, or delimited by a length field, then read the responses line by line in the client using `BufferedReader`, and on the server side, you should add a newline to the end of every message.

Incase the server needs to receive a message, you should add a `new LineBasedFrameDecoder()` at the start of your pipeline, followed by an optional `new StringDecoder()` to let netty automatically turn `ByteBuf`s into strings, you you don't have to do this anymore. Netty can also do this in reverse using a `StringEncoder`, so you can just write a string object, instead of wrapping it every time in a `ByteBuf`.

Comment: I see. 'read(buffer) != -1' holds true if the server closes the socket. However, I don't want that..The protocol is binary based.  Request and response are sent in binary with a fixed header size of 17 bytes and an optional body which is also in binary. Do I need a delimiter, when i know the exact response body size to read from the header ? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Seen the last problem. The entire problem was with the Test Client.
First Problem:
The first was pointed by Ferrybig, in which the `read(buffer) != -1` expects socket closed (Thanks for that man).
Second Problem:
The second was that, the `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter#channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)` never get called as there was nothing to read as the socket doesn't send anything. Editing my client to send something make it work.

New Client:

```
public class TestClient {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9400);
    socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    OutputStream raw = socket.getOutputStream();
    // Will be the request bytes
    raw.write(1);
    raw.flush();

    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    // actual expected size will be here
    final int expectedResponse = 128; 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[expectedResponse];
    int bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
    if (bytesRead != -1) {
        response.append(new String(buffer).trim()).append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("String: " + response.toString());
}
```

}